# Insert the same fixed percentage into multiple rows at once

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have data in this manner:

```
ID       SUB       Marks      
 1      English      25
 2       Maths       22
 3      Science      15
 4      English      16
```

How would I sum the "marks" value with a fixed percentage and give total marks of each ID at once?

For example, if I have a fixed percentage of 10% it should show:

```
ID       SUB       Marks      
 1      English      28
 2       Maths       24
 3      Science      17
 4      English      18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will give you the required `Marks` value:

```
SELECT ID, Marks, ROUND(Marks * 1.1) AS updMarks
FROM mytable
```

If you want to update, then try:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Marks = ROUND(Marks * 1.1)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4db26/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, SUB, Marks + (Marks * 0.10) AS Marks FROM Table
```